# Android Different screen size

Tags: android, size, screen

I made a simple Home dashboard, how do I make it adapt to the various sizes? do I have to create the same activity multiple times and adapt the content or is there another way?

[resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV9TG.png)

[main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkgrq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Linear Layout use Constraint Layout, And also check your layout in landscape mode if layout if not fit according to your requirements, make different arrangement for views in landscape mode too.
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: Thanks for your tip ... changing from Linear to Constraint seems to work

Answer (score 0):

this is the modified file (if anyone can use it)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzr8W.png)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fcfcfc"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.example.homedashboard.MainActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/bank_card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add_card"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ideas_card"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpurple"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Banking"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Check your bank activities"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/ideas_card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/links_card"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bank_card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpink"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_lightbulb_outline_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Ideas"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Check your bank activities"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/add_card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/wifi_card"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/links_card"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bank_card">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_control_point_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Add"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Check your bank activities"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/links_card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/wifi_card"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/add_card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ideas_card">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundyello"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_file_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Links"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Check your bank activities"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/wifi_card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/links_card"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/add_card"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_card">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpurple"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_wifi_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Wifi"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgray" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Check your bank activities"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```